# XML Parsing Error for stache file, used in Tutorial (v2)

Tags: canjs, canjs-component

I'm currently stating to learn CanJS with the [v2 tutorial](https://v2.canjs.com/guides/Tutorial.html).

The  of the index.html consists of the following lines

```
<!-- CanJS application root -->
<div id="can-main"></div>
<script src="libs/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="libs/can.jquery.dev.js"></script>
<script src="libs/can.map.define.js"></script>
<script src="libs/can.stache.js"></script>
<script src="libs/can.fixture.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="components/tut-form/base.js"></script>
```

There is nothing special with `app.js`.
The component JavaScript file (`base.js`) looks like this

```
can.Component.extend({
  tag: 'tutorial-form',
  template: can.view('components/tut-form/base.stache'),
  viewModel: {
    hello: 'Hello Input Component'
  }
});
```

And I've added the tag `<tutorial-form></tutorial-form>` as the last line in the `<body>` of the index.html.

Now at least FF gives the following error

> XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
>   Location: file:///path/to/tutorial/components/tut-form/base.stache
>   Line Number 2, Column 1:

while this file looks like this

```
<h3>Hello</h3>
<h3>{{hello}}</h3>
```

---

Well, I guess, that I'm just missing a CanJS component (I'm using files from the [CanJS .zip](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs.com/archive/v2.3.28.zip), because the [custom download page](https://v2.canjs.com/download.html) is broken or does not look like it is described in the tutorial at all), like `can.Component` or `can.view`. The browser can load the .stache file, but I'm not sure what happens behind the scene.

Does anybody have a hint what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static file server was my solution to this problem. Don't load all the files as `file://`, probably this does not work in FF, too (in Chrome you get a *cross-origin requests not allowed for local files*-like message).

I just configured a NGINX in order to serve the files for this little project, now it works perfectly.

**Sidenote:** Adding a custom tag like `<tutorial-form/>` to the index.html does not work in this case. Instead you need to append this element (a can.Component) to the body like this:

```
$( 'body' ).append( can.stache( '<tutorial-form />' )() );
```